# Passing a qsub command thru ssh2_exec in PHP

Tags: php, bash, qsub, ssh2, ssh2-exec

I have a problem with putting a "qsub" command via "ssh2_exec" in PHP.

when i am running a simple test it works very well:

```
require_once('/apps/phpPackages/vendor/autoload.php');
use phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;
$ssh=new SSH2('xxxxxxxxx');

if (!$ssh->login('xxxxx', 'xxxxxxx')) {
        exit('Login Failed<br>');
}else { echo "SSH Connection established<br>"; }

echo $ssh->exec('echo "Hello World" > test.sh');
```

but when i try to run a qsub command, the qstat shows the job is running but not stopping and the command is not executed at all.

```
require_once('/apps/phpPackages/vendor/autoload.php');
use phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;
$ssh=new SSH2('xxxxxxxxx');

if (!$ssh->login('xxxxx', 'xxxxxxx')) {
        exit('Login Failed<br>');
}else { echo "SSH Connection established<br>"; }

echo $ssh->exec('qsub list_of_command.sh');
```

if I run directly on the terminal `qsub list_of_command.sh`

the job is executed and I have the results needed

Any idea why qsub is not working properly through SSH2 ???

Comment: It is unclear to me what the observed behaviour is. Do you want to say that the `qsub` process started on the remote host, but does not execute any command? Did you verify that the qsub batch server is running on that host?

Comment: YES, the qsub process started on the remote host but it stay on the status "R" running for hours and not excuting the command. the comande is somethink very simple.
and if I run the same directly on the remote host terminal everythink work well.

Comment: My guess gut feeling is that the environment is not set up correctly. My suggestion would be to put a `set -x; set -u; echo STARTED` at the start of your command list script. With this, you should get at least a rudimentary log on standard error, and also an error message if you have an unitialized shell variable. If you don't get ANYTHING on stderr, this is more likely not a programming problem, but related to the qsub configuration. In this case you would have to post your problem at [su].

Comment: I have this set already on the top of my list of commands file. And the test.error and test.log did not give any error just empty files :(
I have feeling that there is somethink missing on the way how to excute `$ssh->exec('qsub list_of_command.sh');`